# sqlserver order of processing records

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which looks like this

```
ID   SchoolName                   SchoolURL     updflag  orderflag
1    Brighton School          Brighton.edu   0      2
2    Andover school               Andover.edu    0       2
3    Fremont school               Fremont.edu    0       2
4    Tulsa Public school          Tulsa.edu      0       1
5    Crescent school          Crescent.edu    0      1
55   NH school                    NH.edu          0      2
61   PennState Univ               pennstate.edu   0      1
2    john Adams public School     Andover.edu     0      2
2    Estabrook school         Andover.edu      0     2
```

I want to print only records that have no duplicates i.e. `ID = 2` shouldn't be printed. I want to select records with `orderflag = 2` first and then show `orderflag = 1`. I also want to show only `10` records at a time. `updflag` gets updated to `1` if I update the record.

```
SELECT   TOP 10 r.orderflag,r.[id],
                     r.schoolurl,
                     updatedflag
                    FROM     [dbo].[schools] AS r

                    INNER JOIN
                    (SELECT   id
                    FROM     [dbo].[schools]
                    GROUP BY id
                    HAVING   COUNT(*) = 1) AS k
                    ON k.id = r.id
                    WHERE   updflag = 0 
                    GROUP BY r.orderflag,r.id, School URL, updflag order by r.orderflag desc;
```

I have millions of records and I want to make I process `orderflag = 2` first and then `orderflag = 1`. How can I do this?

Thanks
R

Comment: TOP 10 needs an ORDER BY to be meaningful. Why is there no ORDER BY here?

Comment: Yes. OrderBy is SQL 102 - right after SELECT. Without OrderBy there IS NO ORDER. Want an order, put one in. Sets have no order. Sql is set based.

Comment: I do have "order by r.orderflag desc".

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach would be to simply exclude those in which there is a `COUNT > 1` for the `ID`:

```
SELECT ... FROM schools
WHERE ID NOT IN (
    SELECT ID FROM schools
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1
)
```

Next, to handle the order flags, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM schools
WHERE orderflag = 2 AND
    ID NOT IN (
        SELECT ID FROM schools
        WHERE orderflag = 2
        GROUP BY ID
        HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1
    )
UNION
SELECT ... FROM schools
WHERE orderflag = 1 AND
    ID NOT IN (
        SELECT ID FROM schools
        WHERE orderflag = 1
        GROUP BY ID
        HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1
    )
```